# Hands of rig move to weird positions after re-mapping animation with ARP

Tags: animation, rigging, auto-rig-pro

I wanted to re-map a simple motion capture animation to a model I rigged with AutoRigPro. The rig seems fine, everything in the re-targeting stage seems fine and the first frame of the animation (T-pose) also is perfectly fine. However on frame 2, the hands move to (seemingly) the mirrored side of the rig. I tried manually switching left and right hand bones, and even entire body halves, but that just made a bigger mess.

[image: Source rig bottom, target rig on top]

Is there anything I'm missing? Everything else works as intended, head, torso, legs, you name it. Just the hands do what is shown in the picture.

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Can you attach your .blend file? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, of course.  https://blend-exchange.com/b/SKW2raMm/